# SalesForce JWT in C# - private key issue with ForceDotNetJwtCompanion

Tags: c#, jwt, salesforce

I am trying to connect to Salesforce via the JWT authentication method using the ForceDotNetJwtCompanion NuGet package and am running into issues. I am admittedly very new to cryptography so please forgive my lack of knowledge.

Based on the example given on the ForceDotNetJwtCompanion github page, I have attempted to implement the section under 'usage in code' https://github.com/claboran/ForceDotNetJwtCompanion

```
            string certificatePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Resources\\cert.keys.p12";
            X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, "pw", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            RSA certPrivateKey = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
            string privateKeyXML = certPrivateKey.ToXmlString(false);

            var apiVersion = "v50.0";
            var privateKey = privateKeyXML;
            var passPhrase = "passphrase";
            var isProd = true;
            var authClient = new JwtAuthenticationClient(apiVersion, isProd);

            await authClient.JwtPrivateKeyAsync(
                "value_that_ive_removed",
                privateKey,
                passPhrase,
                "user@company.com",
                "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token"
                );
            var accessToken = authClient.AccessToken;
```

To facilitate this, I've got a p12 certificate I've loaded and extracted the private key. I get an error on the call for await authClient.JwtPrivateKeyAsync:

```
    System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=ForceDotNetJwtCompanion
  StackTrace:
   at ForceDotNetJwtCompanion.Util.KeyHelpers.CreatePrivateKeyWrapperWithPassPhrase(String key, String passphrase)
   at ForceDotNetJwtCompanion.JwtAuthenticationClient.<JwtPrivateKeyAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
```

I believe it may be because my privatekey string is in XML format (I have verified there's a Modulus and Exponent in the XML data) but I am not sure. The method giving a null reference xception only deals with the key and passphrase values so I assume it does not like my privatekey although I don't see any documentation as to what it is actually expecting. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The private key needs to be in PEM format. Please create your key with openssl like it has been described here:

```bash
openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:secret -out server.pass.key 2048
openssl rsa -passin pass:secret -in server.pass.key -out server.key
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```